# How can I use multiple quotation marks in the system() function?

Tags: c, string, character, system

I'm using:

`char s[20]=system("vcgencmd | egrep "[0-9.]{4,}" -o");`

The `system()` function has problems with the the number of quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to have a traditional C-style string that contains double quotation characters, then you can just restructure your expression to be the following:

```
 char s[20] = system("vcgencmd | egrep \"[0-9.]{4,}\" -o");
```

In this case, each double quotation mark that appears inside the string is denoted by **\"**

the `\` character is called an [Escape Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: Well, I'd like to store the string returned from the system call (on Linux) into a character array.